# Error message. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, sql, web

Hi there I'm getting this error everytime I try to attempt an update statement "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax".

Here is update statement:

```
$update = "UPDATE web_products SET 
product_name='$product_name', product_id='$product_id', 
listing_price='$product_price', brand='$product_brand',
product_description='$product_description',rating='$rating', 
reviews= '$reviews' WHERE id =$id ";

echo $update;
```

`UPDATE web_products, SET product_name='Women's adidas Originals
Sleek Shoes',
product_id='G27341',
listing_price='7599',
brand='Adidas ORIGINALS',
product_description='A modern take on adidas sport
heritage, tailored just for women. Perforated 3-Stripes on the
leather
upper of these shoes offer a sleek look that mirrors iconic tennis
styles.',
rating='3.3',
reviews= '24'
WHERE id =3

So this is the error message I get once i try the update:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET product_name='Womens adidas Originals NMD_Racer Primeknit Shoes', product_' at line 1

Can anyone help?

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with parameter values.

Comment: Please show the echoed query and the full error message, it might help with finding the issue. But as Gordon suggested, using prepared statements and parameter binding resolves a LOT of syntax issues

Comment: `web_products, SET` There's a comma coming in from somewhere

Comment: Looks like it may be the un-escaped apostrophe in the product name.

Comment: Thanks all, Yeah there's a few apostrophe's and commas within the dataset itself that was causing the problem. I've tried it with these taken out and the update works perfect. thanks again for noticing these.